Residual Connection in Pytorch
I have a VNET network (see here for reference) There are two types of skip connections in the paper. Concatenating two tensors and element wise add. I think i am implementing the second one wrong, because when i remove the addition (the +x in the code) , the networks starts to learn, but when i leave it in the loss is constantly at 1.
Here is my implementations. You can see the add connection here after the first for loop, in between the two loops and the last line of the second for loop.
Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?
  def forward(self,x):
    skip_connections = []
    
    for i in range(len(self.first_forward_layers)):
        x = self.first_forward_layers[i](x) +x
        skip_connections.append(x)
        x = self.down_convs[i](x) 
   
    x = self.final_conv(x) +x    


    for i in range(len(self.second_forward_layers)):
        x = self.up_convs[i](x)
        skip = skip_connections.pop()
        concatenated= torch.cat((skip,x),dim=1)
        x = self.second_forward_layers[i](concatenated) +x
        
    x = self.last_layer(x) 
    return x

